# Puzzle Quest 2: Gate Hacker Achievement

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

I made what appears to be a mistake by "picking locks" for some of the doors when I started out on my quests in Puzzle Quest 2. Am I going to need to start over with a new character and bash all of the doors in order to get the Gate Hacker achievement?

Comment: I suggest adding an xbox live arcade tag (or something like it) so that it's clear that this doesn't apply to the DS version of PQ II.

Comment: @KatieK does the DS version of PQII have achievements?

Comment: @tzenes Ther's is no Achievement in the DS version.

Comment: @Dav I think my question was largely rhetorical.

Comment: @tzenes Are you sure?

Comment: @Dav you win this round

Comment: @tzenes +1 for Sportsmanship

Comment: FWIW, this also applies to the Steam version, which has the same Gate Hacker achievement and thus the same requirement (that if given the option to bash, you must take it).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you *will* need to start over with a new character in order to get the Gate Hacker achievement. You have to choose "Bash" on *all* gates, doors, and chests in order to receive it, even if they have other opening options. You receive credit for the achievement after you complete the game, not after you bash the last door.